# Best place to attach javascript behaviour to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a Javascript file that provides the functionality to create certain DOM elements with ease.

Coming from a jQuery background, normally I'd make this file a plugin and set it up with:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.entryPoint = function(options) {
        //do stuff
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I have no desire to use jQuery for this script, however.

What's the best way to attach the behaviour I've just written to the DOM in a fashion that has the same meaning as the jQuery plugin notation presented above?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The jQuery mechanism doesn't attach the script to the DOM, it just defines a function in the jQuery namespace.

Comment: The above code doesn't do anything special, are saying about `ready` handler

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I'm aware of that. I was after the equivalent in a jQuery-free environment.
@ArunPJohny I'm not referring to the `ready` handler, I was just wondering where I should add the function to the DOM for a roughly analogous structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal **best code** for anything. It all depends on what you are trying to do. I might do something like this, which gives a single global variable named entryPoint, enclosed so that nothing else leaks out into the global namespace.

```
(function(w) {
    w.entryPoint = function(options) {
        //do stuff
    }
})(window);
```